# How can I use style or stylesheets in VSTS Wiki?

Tags: html, css, azure-devops, wiki

**Visual Studio Team Services** has now got built-in support for creating and maintain **[Wiki-pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/markdown-guidance#html-tags)** using standard Markdown or plain HTML. For the overview page, I would like to use HTML-tags so that I can create 'blocks' of subjects that link to other pages on the Wiki. As is usual with HTML, I would like to create a **css-class** that will be used by each block to set its style, like *width, height, padding*, etc. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do this (or to find out if this is supported at all). If I put in plain HTML like so, it just works:

```
<div style="...">
    A
</div>

<div style="...">
    B
</div>
```

But if I want to apply the same styles using a style-tag it doesn't work:

```
<style>
   .subject {
       ...
   }
</style>

<div class="subject">
    A
</div>

<div class="subject">
    B
</div>
```

There also doesn't seem to be a way to upload and/or include stylesheets into the page or Wiki.

Does anyone now *if* and *how* I can declare css-styles on VSTS Wiki pages this way? I know there's a simple workaround, but it would be great to be able to use css-classes and styles the regular way....

Answer (score 2):

I can also reproduce the issue when html contains stylesheets in VSTS wili page.

And I reported the item [HTML style can not be recognized in VSTS wiki page](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/207078/html-style-can-not-be-recognized-in-vsts-wiki-page.html) for the issue, you can follow up.

Comment: Here is a link to UserVoice to vote on this feature request: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/31295473-allow-custom-css-for-the-wiki

Comment: User voice instance is no longer active. Looks like this is the best place to vote as of 2019-10-25 https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365758/allow-custom-css-for-the-wiki.html